# How can I implement two kinds of login with Django?

Tags: python, django

How can I implement two kinds of logins with Django?
For example,

1, Employee login - Employee page

2, Supervisor login - Supervisor page.

Finally I succeeded with this code.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
  is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class LoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "registration/login.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        user = User.objects.filter(username=self.request.POST['username'])
        if user.is_employee:
            return reverse('teacher')
         else:
            return reverse('student')
```

Comment: Refer to this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Comment: Thank you. I can see about signup but no about login. My App will be internal so people can't signup for my App. Admin will give students and teachers usernames and passwords. So I just need the login and logout function.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the Identity in your User model, like this:

```
identity = (("students", "students"),
            ("teachers", "teachers"),
            ("Admin", "Admin"))
class User(AbstractUser):
    ......
    identity = models.CharField(choices=identity)
```

and in `views.py`, when user login, check the Identity and lead to the right page.

```
def login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if not user:    # authentication fails
        messages.error(request, 'Error')
        return render(request, template)
    ......
    auth_login(request, user)

    if request.user.identity == "students":
        return redirect('students:students')
    elif request.user.identity == "teachers":
        return redirect('teachers:teachers')
    else:
        return redirect('admin:admin')
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I get the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Auth Backends in the docs.

You can define different login patterns for different kind of users

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I get the solution above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use multi level user here.According to role based they will have access in different authorized pages.

Hopefully this will help you.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Comment: Thank you. I can see about signup but no about login. My App will be internal so people can't signup for my App. Admin will give students and teachers usernames and passwords. So I just need the login and logout function.

Comment: @Leaner, you didn't mention it in your question please. If admin can set the role of user and depend on the user role views method will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I get the solution above.